# ionic serve fails on git bash

Tags: npm, ionic3, git-bash

I'm using ionic 3, after starting the project, the command `ionic serve` gives the following error:

```
[app-scripts] 'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[app-scripts] operable program or batch file.

[INFO] Looks like @ionic/app-scripts isn't installed in this project.

       This package is required for this command to work properly. The
 package provides a CLI utility, but the ionic-app-scripts binary was not found in your PATH.
```

I tried removing the `node_modules` and running `npm install` right after, but still getting the same error.

Is there any work around? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They have the same error here:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3399

You should try

`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`

and then

`npm install`

Comment: I just switched back to linux, i hope the answer could help others.